# How long do summoned beings last?

Tags: summoning, duration, world-of-dungeons

My friends and I are looking to play [World of Dungeons](http://apocalypse-world.com/pbta/games/title/World_of_Dungeons), but I'm a little confused about the magic system:

> Most magic requires summoning a spirit, demon, or elemental to perform supernatural effects. A Wizard begins play with the occult knowledge to summon 
>   two spirits. A spirit has a name, an appearance, and two domains of power (flame, shadow, stone, lightning, secrets, fear, etc.).
>
> To summon a spirit you know, you require one of the following:
>
> - 1 hour of uninterrupted ritual.
> - A dose of quicksilver—a mild poison and addictive drug. (10s per use). If you drink more quicksilver doses in a day than your Level you must attempt to resist its negative effects with a CON roll.
> - A magic item containing a bound spirit.
>
> A Wizard may command a spirit to perform a single magical effect that falls within its domains (it’s a good idea to give specific commands; spirits and demons can be capricious and cruel). Magical attacks do 2d6+level or 3d6+level damage if they are especially suited to the situation (using fire against a Frost Wraith, for example).

Is the summoned being single-use, since it performs 'a single magical effect'? It doesn't really seem right to have to summon a new spirit for every spell - but infinite uses seems overpowered too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Commanding a Spirit is a move, and you do it one magical effect at a time

So, for example, you have a spirit of smoke and shadow.  You take an hour to summon it, while the party barricades the door to keep the orcs at bay.  When they break in after you finish summoning, you can command it to fill the entrance with smoke, stinging their eyes and making it difficult for them to breathe. Then, after that works out successfully, you can command the spirit to yank an orc by their shadow and hurl them against the wall, which is a magical attack.  You can't have the spirit fill the area with smoke *and* telekinesis some orc shadows at the same time; that would be two magical effects.  You also probably have to telekinesis the orcs one at a time, because doing multiple would probably be too much like two different effects, but maybe not depending on what's going on with how magic/your spirit works in your fiction.

The spirits stay out as long as you want but "spirits and demons
can be capricious and cruel" which means that if you have a summoned spirit around the GM is going to be using 'Turn their move back on them' and 'Show a downside to their class, race, or equipment' a lot.

Comment: Cool, thanks! I will probably accept tomorrow if no one else chimes in